# Por que a expressão "porque eu quis" é considerada ofensiva?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Estou com uma dúvida há bastante tempo, por que a expressão *"Porque eu quis"* para indicar a vontade própria de realizar determinada ação é considerada ofensiva e rude?

Comment: Na minha visão depende do contexto e do tom de voz — para mim, “eu fiz porque eu quis, né, meu ‘fíio’” não soa ofensivo. Mas acho, puro achismo, que ela é ofensiva porque geralmente é usada quando não se quer responder ao motivo da ação, dizendo que o motivo é a própria vontade e que não há nada mais, ou seja, uma tentativa de se esquivar a responder à pergunta, o que já é meio considerado rude. Novamente, isto é apenas achismo.

Comment: Penso que a resposta que @Schilive coloca em seu comentário é correta, e mais que achismo. A resposta "porque eu quis" só contém alguma informação num contexto em que a dúvida é sobre a pessoa ter sido constrangida a uma ação - caso contrário, está no mesmo grupo que "não te interessa".

Comment: @Schilive Entendi, então tudo depende do contexto? E como eu digo "_porque eu quis_" de uma forma que não soa tão rude e indelicada?

Comment: Mas @stafusa, "_não te interessa_" não é uma frase que deveria ser considerada rude, concorda? Sim, eu sei que há formas menos agressivas de dizer que o assunto não é de interesse da pessoa, o que me intriga mais é o por quê dessas frases serem consideradas rudes, sendo que são apenas apontamentos.

Comment: LouizCtx, você tem razão - dependendo, por exemplo, do tom de voz utilizado, pode não ser rude. Mas na grande maioria das vezes acaba sendo, porque uma pergunta dessas assume interesse e razoabilidade da questão, que são negadas por uma resposta como "porque eu quis". Ela essencialmente significa na verdade "não quero te dizer": só que sem a sinceridade desta última.

Comment: @LouizCtx, eu sou uma pessoa mais direta na fala oral, então, “porque eu quis” não me soa tão rude se não houver um tom rude ou uma óbvia intenção de ser rude. Por exemplo, “eu fiz um robozinho que canta ópera” diz Maria Lúcia, então, pergunta-lhe Mario Lúcio “por quê?” e Maria Lúcia lhe reponde “porque eu quis! Não é legal este robozinho cantando ópera?!” disse Maria entusiasmadamente. Nesse exemplo, “porque eu quis” não rude ao meu ver. Porém, “eu fiz porque eu quis!” disse João Roberto, então, disse ele “O quê? Não gosto? Ohhhh, que dó! Quer leitinho, bebê?”. >>

Comment: >> Nesse segundo exemplo, João Roberto está sendo rude. A maior diferença entre os dois “porque eu quis” são o tom e a intenção, pelo que vejo, i.e., o modo. O resto dos exemplos é para negritar a diferença do jeito que a pessoa está falando, ou seja, que não são apenas as palavras.

Comment: @stafusa saquei, valeu!

Comment: @Schilive faz sentido cara, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Essa frase além do falado acima também expressa o egoísmo e negligência para o outro.
O fato de você fazer algo simplesmente por que você quis e não se importar com o outro ou com as vontades dele. Pelo menos é o que é inferido.
Um outro exemplo é que é muito comum um diálogo.
"Mas mãe por que não/sim?"
"Por que não/sim."
Pode-se ver que nessa frase você corta completamente a possibilidade de diálogo. Nesse sentido são similares.

Answer (score 1):

Esta frase pode ter o mesmo sentido de "não é da sua conta".

Demonstra insubordinação.

Expressa ao interlocutor que suas ideais são irrelevantes para a solução do problema.

Uma alternativa seria:
"Bem, eu imaginei que agindo dessa maneira seria proveitoso".

Answer (score 1):

Conforme já foi dito em comentários, o fato de ser ofensivo ou não, depende muito da entonacão e expressão facial.  Eu diria que em mais de 95% dos casos "porque eu quis" significa "não te interessa" ou "não é da sua conta".

Isso pode ser dito de forma ríspida, de forma educada, ou até mesmo carinhosa. Com o significado de "não é da sua conta", essa resposta pode variar de "neutra" até "muito ofensiva".

Answer (score 0):

"Porque eu quis" é ofensivo e rude, essa expressão em português deixa desabrochar o que há no íntimo, sendo que existem outras variáveis para ser mais cordial com o próximo, devido à vasta variedade linguística existente na língua portuguesa.

Portanto, independentemente do contexto em que a frase "porque eu quis" é empregada, considera-se indelicada.

Comment: Como assim no íntimo? "_Porque eu quis_" deixa implícito que eu estou desprezando a pessoa na qual estou respondendo?

Answer (score 0):

Existem vários fatores à considerar. Entre eles o contexto e a entonação. Se levarmos em consideração o contexto, geralmente o receptor da mensagem a encara como ofensiva quando o ato cometido o atingiu de alguma forma, dando a entender que o autor não teve empatia durante a prática. Quando a frase em questão é dita com mais firmeza, então, é considerável grosseria. Sendo assim, a junção da entonação e interpretação do contexto gera uma ideia de ofensa.

Comment: Entendi, então sempre dependemos do contexto para esse tipo de frase, saquei! Obrigado